# Delete files older than 15 days except for monthly and annual versions

Tags: find, tar, delete

I use a simple find script to delete backup tar files older than 30 days, but in the interest of historical preservation and having the ability to look back further, I'd like to switch to keeping the last 15 days, and also any backups created on the first of each month (for 12 months) and the first of each year (going back 12 years).  What's the most elegant way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

If your files have the proper filesystem-level timestamps *and* the date is included in the filename (e.g. `backup-20230713.tar.gz` or so), then something like this:

```
# delete files older than 30 days, except ones from the first of each month
find . -name 'backup-*.tar.gz' -mtime +30 ! -name '*-??????01.tar.gz' -delete

# delete files older than a year, except ones from January 1st
find . -name 'backup-*.tar.gz' -mtime +366 ! -name '*-????0101.tar.gz' -delete

# delete everything older than 12 years:
find . -name 'backup-*.tar.gz' -mtime +$(( 12 * 366 )) -delete
```

Alternatively, just place the files in separate directories according to "group" when creating them, e.g. the first of each year goes to `yearly/`, similarly for `monthly/`, and the rest in `daily/`. Then just do:

```
find daily/   -mtime +30 -delete
find monthly/ -mtime +366 -delete
find yearly/  -mtime +$((12 * 366)) -delete
```

You should probably test anything like that extensively before using. (Create test files with `touch -d` etc. and try the `find` commands without the `-delete`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you.  I agree that subdirs would be neater, although I'm not sure the find commands as you have them written would accomplish keeping monthly/yearly versions; Using the named exclusions find command should work great! (edit- just hit me, you intended daily/monthly/annual backups to be placed in respective subdirs. Yes, that would be better!  In my use-case, I have no control over the backup routines)

Comment: @user162124, yes indeed. I figure it'd be easier to separate the files into different "groups" immediately when creating them, rather than sort them out later. Of course that requires modifying the way the files are created, or at least tacking on another script to move the newest one in the correct directory.

Comment: As I'm looking to implement this strategy across various hosts, I'm noticing that not all file names are in enough of a consistent format as to allow a truly backup-process agnostic script.  Wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish this task using just system timestamps.

Comment: @user162124 Yes. See my rawhide (rh) answer. It doesn't rely on any filename conventions. It works based entirely on file modification timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of the *rawhide* (*rh*) program used in this answer (at https://github.com/raforg/rawhide).

*rh* (and *find*) can compare modification times against reference files whose modification times can be specified precisely with `touch -t YYYYMMDDhhmm`.

Below is a shell script that chdirs to the backup directory and creates a timestamped reference file for the first of the month for each of the past twelve months, and the first of January for each of the past twelve years.

Then it calls *rh* to list the files (with *rh*'s `-l` option) that need to be deleted according to your specification.

It has a `-D` option that deletes the files instead (with *rh*'s `-UUU` option).

The search criteria first defines a helper function that returns true when the file was last modified on the given day (i.e. between the given time and a day later):

```
on(givenday) { mtime >= givenday && mtime < givenday + day }
```

The search criteria then matches regular files (`f`) that are tarfiles (`"*.tar*"`) and that are at least 15 days old (`old(15*days)`), and that weren't last modified on the first of the month for any of the past twelve months, or on the first of January for any of the past twelve years (e.g., `!on("1st00".mtime) && ...`).

Then it deletes the timestamped reference files.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Delete backup tarfiles that are older than 15 days except those created
# on the 1st of the month for the past 12 months, and those created on the
# first of January for the past 12 years.

# usage: $0 [-D]
# The -D option deletes files. Without it, they are listed.

# Set this to the path to the backups
path=/path/to/backups

opts=-l
case "$1" in
    -D)
        opts="-UUU"
        ;;
    ?*)
        echo usage: $0 [-D]
        echo "The -D option deletes files (with exceptions)."
        echo "Without it, they will be listed instead."
        echo Files in $path will be listed or deleted.
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

cd "$path" || exit 1

# Create timstamped reference files for the 1st Jan (past 12 years)

year=`date +%Y`
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
do
    y=`expr $year - $i`
    touch -t ${y}01010000 1stJan`printf %02d $i`
done

# Create timstamped reference files for the 1st of the month (past 12 months)

month=`date +%m`
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
do
    touch -t $year${month}010000 1st`printf %02d $i`
    if [ $month = 01 ]
    then
        month=12
        year=`expr $year - 1`
    else
        month=`expr $month - 1`
        month=`printf '%02d' $month`
    fi
done

# Delete the backup tarfiles

rh $opts '

    # Define a helper function to make the rest easier to read.
    # True when mtime is on the given day.
    on(givenday) { mtime >= givenday && mtime < givenday + day }

    # Tar files at least 15 days old
    f && "*.tar*" && old(15*days) &&

    # Not last modified on the 1st of the past 12 months
    !on("1st00".mtime) &&
    !on("1st01".mtime) &&
    !on("1st02".mtime) &&
    !on("1st03".mtime) &&
    !on("1st04".mtime) &&
    !on("1st05".mtime) &&
    !on("1st06".mtime) &&
    !on("1st07".mtime) &&
    !on("1st08".mtime) &&
    !on("1st09".mtime) &&
    !on("1st10".mtime) &&
    !on("1st11".mtime) &&
    !on("1st12".mtime) &&

    # Not last modified on the 1st of January for the past 12 years
    !on("1stJan00".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan01".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan02".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan03".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan04".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan05".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan06".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan07".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan08".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan09".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan10".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan11".mtime) &&
    !on("1stJan12".mtime)

'

# Clean up the timestamped reference files

rm 1st[01][0-9] 1stJan[01][0-9]
```

It's hard-coded to a single backup directory but it'd be easy enough to make it take a directory on the command line. It might be dangerous to do that, though. Be careful out there.

The same thing could be done in *find* in much the same way, just with different syntax, more of it, and twice as many timestamped reference files.

Comment: @user162124 I've just edited it to correctly handle the requirement about the past 12 months. The original version based on subtracting average month lengths was not helpful. And I've refactored the search criteria to be much easier to read.